# How do I show special characters inside a div without messing up the codes?

Tags: php, html

I have the following html/php code:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 description-status-row" title = "'.$element['description'].'">
    '.$description.' 
</div>
```

`$element['description']` contains special characters which is the ff:

> NG   - 55205 - Cannot execute Program line. Machine data read error (incorrect setup of MXF parameters). Center 1 :IF ( TX < RDM("ponte_registro""1"="" "mindgxcarrelgloy2") * 1 m) = " "   " = " "

The `<RDM` part is messing up my codes and closing the `</div>` How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Try using htmlspecialchars($element['descrption']) instead

Comment: `<` is being interperted as the opening tag of a HTML tag. Use `htmlspecialchars()` to replace it with `&lt;`, so it appears the same visually, but doesn't break your HTML.

Comment: Why using special characters in the title attribute of the div? You could clean it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)